# Facebook - get photo by id and set width & height

Tags: php, facebook

I have to get a photo by id and set width and height of this photo.

I tried that:

```
$photo_thumb = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$attachments[$i]['target']['id'].'/picture?width=400&height=200&redirect=false&access_token='.$token);
$photo_thumb = json_decode($photo_thumb, true);
```

and finally i get this:

```
array(1) {
  ["data"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["is_silhouette"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["url"]=>
    string(110) "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xtl1/t31.0-8/s720x720/12496360_127798700941215_6417691067208545145_o.jpg"
  }
}
```

This returned photo is 720 x 720. Why? I set 400 x 200. Anyone can tell me why it doesn't work and how repair it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook does not return just any width or height you define in the parameters.  Why don't you try testing here:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=user_id%2Fpicture

The image width and height you specify are more suggestions than requirements in this API call.  If you need an image of a specific aspect ratio or width and height, you'd be better off downloading the image and manipulating it yourself using an extension like GD2.